# Son erased the play store app

Tags: google-play-store

My son accidentally erased the play store from his next book tablet. Is there anyway I can get it back? Would resetting the tablet bring it back?

Comment: Not sure how he did that; are you sure he's not just removed the icon from the homescreen?  What happens if you go to the Play Store online (https://play.google.com/store) and download something (anything) and while it's downloading select the app; does that take you to the Play Store?

Comment: I've looked everywhere and I can't find it. When I go online to try and download something, it won't let me.

Comment: As the playstore app is a *system app*, it cannot be "erased by accident" (except with root-powers). So I second Poldie. To add: Also check *settings→apps* on the "all" tab. Maybe he just *disabled* it. If it's there and shows "disabled", open the entry, and tap the "enable" button.

Comment: "It won't let me" is rather vague. I'm suggesting you use a regular PC to download the app using the link I provided, onto your phone (it'll push it onto it over 3G/wifi).

Comment: It's not my phone, it's his tablet. I've been into settings, I've looked everywhere. There is no sign of the play store anywhere. I can only get to the play store if I search for it online. It won't let me put any games on the tablet going that route. If I reset it will it put it back on?

Comment: The next book tablet does come with it. I bought two and they already had it.

Comment: maybe the store had pre-installed them.

Comment: Will it work if I reset it?

Comment: I don't think so, because the initial state of the tablet has no PlayStore

Comment: WalMart installs?

Answer (score 1):

By default `NextBook` Tablets comes with no `PlayStore` Application, so you will need to re-download (re-install) the `PlayStore` **Manually**

check this link, it may help you
http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/how-can-i-download-google-play-to-my-nextbook-tablet/

Answer (score 0):

I found the apk (the installer binary file) by searching on Google. Here is a link to the file which if you access on your phone, will install the latest version of the Google Play Store.

https://mega.co.nz/#!hJ8ynBKI!aYGtlxZNcO4BvDSsNyAk7DOj6ppHE5apNaVcAktPmAk

PS: I cannot claim that this file is actually what it says it is, just a suggestion that looks legit.